# Automation test of a chat application with appium

Tags: automated-tests, appium, android-espresso, android-testing, appium-android

I've to test an android application. It's almost like WhatsApp. Its functionalities are

1. Sending message
2. Different type of attachment
3. Delete message
4. Reply on message
5. Send contact
6. Share location
7. Share video/audio
8. Record audio and send
9. Audio calling
10. Video calling

I'm new in testing. I came to know about **Appium** for testing android and ios application. I can send message or file easily with appium but how can I verify wheather the test case of sending message or attachment is successfull automatically with appium? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to log out from sender and login to receiver account to verify if the message is sent successfully. Alternatively you can create two different appium driver sessions on two devices and you can simultaneously test both sent and received message on two phones.